# How to re display tooltip after mouse move

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using a canvas to present several UI components. I am setting `canvas.title` to present the help for each component.

```
...
if(mouse.y >= y && mouse.y <= y + w && mouse.over){
    if(currentId !== tool.id){
        canvas.title = tool.help;
    }
    currentId = tool.id;
...
```

The problem is that when the mouse moves the tool tip is hidden and will not re display until I move the mouse out and then move back onto the canvas.

I would like to change the behaviour so that the tool tip displays again when I hover over another UI component without leaving the canvas element?

Comment: Hmmm ... just native tooltip -- no custom tooltip using div-show-on-mouse-event allowed? Let's see: 1. You've already tried changing the title.  2. No "html tooltip display settings" appears to exist. 3. Manually triggering mouseover / mouseenter doesn't work, 4. Hiding & reshowing the canvas doesn't work. 5. Temporarily repositioning the canvas with position:absolute doesn't work. I give up ... what's the answer?

Comment: @markE The answer? wish I knew, was hoping it is not "No.. Not possible!" Only one I have not tried is the event triggers. Must try that before I accept any answer.

Comment: I really thought you were going to self-post the answer. :-) I tried triggering the likely events...no luck. Perhaps events in combination with altering the CSS visibility, position, etc -- but I'm not hopeful? Just curious ... why not use the typical (and more customizable) div-show-on-mouse-event type of tooltip?

Comment: @markE Just tried every variant of events and no luck. Am flat out and needed a quick answer. Looks like I will go for the custom tooltip using my favourite DOM element, canvas. Normally the tooltips are on the same canvas but this time the canvas is one of many on the page and so none have the room and they are all render on demand so don't lend themselves to nice fades etc.. Oh well another item on the todo list... Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your custom tooltip gives more freedom and control.

This is a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/mynetx/5qbP3/ 
You can take ideas and build from here. Another advantage is control over the CSS which in cases like yours, where you want to provide help.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
var couponcodes = document.getElementsByClassName("couponcode");
for (var i = 0; i < couponcodes.length; i++) {
    couponcodes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        var coupontooltip = this.getElementsByClassName("coupontooltip")[0];
        coupontooltip.removeAttribute("style");
    });
    couponcodes[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        var coupontooltip = this.getElementsByClassName("coupontooltip")[0];
        coupontooltip.style.display = "none";
    });
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips are part of the system the browser runs in and sadly aren't accessible in any way from JavaScript.

I would recommend implementing your own tooltip, which is not very hard (both on canvas and using an extra element).

If you are worried about accessibility—it's possible to give an element "tooltip" role: http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tooltip.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use fabric.js. see [this](http://fabricjs.com/hovering).